# Is `open()`, `mmap()`, or neither, the more fundamental function?

Tags: linux, files, c

In the Linux kernel, is `open()`, `mmap()` or neither, the more fundamental way to access a file? By "fundamental", I mean "does either ultimately call the other or a simple helper function of the other?".

There are a lot of questions on the stack network asking about the performance of these two functions. The hope of this question is to get at what is going on inside the Linux kernel a priori. Does `open()` call `mmap()` or some helper function that essentially implements `mmap()`? Alternatively, does `mmap()` call `open()` or call some helper function that essentially implements `open()`?

The gist of the question is whether these two system calls are *fundamentally* different or whether one is a "convenience function" of the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) often wants a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) usually provided by [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html); in that sense, `open` is more fundamental. Notice also that the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of some [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) is modified not only by `mmap`, `munmap`, [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) but also by other [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (including [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html); see also [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html))

BTW, the Linux kernel don't *use* `mmap` or `open` but provides and implements them (for application-level [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) programs).

But the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) manages the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) which is more fundamental and related to *both* [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). See also [LinuxAteMyRam](http://linuxatemyram.com/) and consider *perhaps* using [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html), [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) to give hints to the page cache subsystem.

> whether these two system calls are fundamentally different

All system calls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) are different.

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (both are freely downloadable).

Comment: Thank for pointing out `mmap()` wanting a file descriptor from `open()`. I guess I should have said `open()` + `read()`/`write()` vs `mmap()` + `read()`/`write()`?

Comment: @Praxeolitic, the point of `mmap()` is that you don't use `read()`/`write()` to access the file's data, the data is mapped in the process' address space (pulled on-demand from the file by the kernel through the MMU's page fault mechanism instead of the user explicitely requesting the kernel with a `read()` system call)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oops. I should have said mmap() + reading/writing.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're naming functions, we assume you already know that calling `mmap()` on a file requires an fd, which is typically (but not always) created with `open()`.

Unless you use O_DIRECT, in kernels like Linux with a "unified buffer cache", `read()` and `write()` operate on the same page cache which is mapped in by `mmap()`.  However this ignores the performance tradeoffs of each method, so it does not seem a very useful answer.

Outside of obtaining a book, Google finds a [nice and short description of mmap and regular IO v.s. the page cache](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files/).  It does not mention the performance *costs* of `mmap()`, as per the [quote from Linus Torvalds](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0004.0/0728.html) which you've probably already seen.

Comment: I will read your link (I've encountered that site before and it's excellent). In the mean time (I'll probably sleep ~8 hrs before I read the link), is there anything I should specify to help narrow down the question to one with a more definitive answer? For example, would specifying "sequential reading of an entire file" help?

Comment: Also, if you were to suggest obtaining a book, what would it be? Thanks.

Comment: @Praxeolitic Not sure, I mostly said that because I got a Safari link in my search results :).